# identifying a bean in jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

I am analyzing a jsp page. In this jsp page I found the following code.

Here I can understand that customer is jsp bean.

```
<c:if test="${empty customer}">             
    /*-----
    ....*/
</c:if>
```

I thought of finding the definition of customer bean and its linking to jsp. I searched all the tlds in my project. But could not find it.

Can some one guide me to find the definition for customer bean(How exactly it is linked to JSP).

Answer (score 0):

You probably won't find a link from the bean to the jsp, such a coupling would be uneccessary, or worse, dangerous in my opinion. Better just look for a `customer` bean by directly searching for it in your project(s) via the IDE. Try looking for the reference at the point of the servlet where you bind the bean to the jsp.